# Kendo UI: Open window larger than containing window

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a web page that opens a kendoWindow (A); the content is an iframe that contains a web page that opens another kendoWindow (B). The problem is that window B is larger than window A, so it's not shown correctly. My objective is to show window B (in its full size) on top of window A, is this possible?

UPDATE:

This is the code; note that the iframe is larger than the window, but I need the iframe on top of the window, not inside it:

```
    <div id="iframewin">
        <iframe name="iframe" id="iframe" frameborder="0" />
    </div>

     $('#iframe').width('800px');
     $('#iframe').height('400px');

     $("#iframewin").kendoWindow({
             width:  "600px",
             height: "300px",
             visible : true
         });

      $("#iframewin").data("kendoWindow").center();
      $("#iframewin").data("kendoWindow").open();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem should be the ifram , kendo window does not need a iframe to load the content

```
<div id="window"></div>


var window = $("#window"),
    if (!window.data("kendoWindow")) {
        window.kendoWindow({
          Height:"500px" // if you need full screen give 100% for both height and width
          width: "600px", // if you need the window to fix to your content remove H & W 
          title: "About Alvar Aalto",
          iframe: true, // if you need to load as a iframe 
          actions: ["Pin","Minimize","Maximize","Close"],
          content: "Content.html",
          });
     }
window .data("kendoWindow").center();
window .data("kendoWindow").open();
```

you can give a url to the refresh method also window .data("kendoWindow").refresh(URl);
check the live Demo for more information http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/ajax